# Updating django object

Tags: django

I'm writing django website connected with web scraping and I stopped at updating my Driver object. 
I don't know why it doesn't work properly. Here is some HTML code.

```
<form action="{% url 'update' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for driver in new_drivers %}
    <label for="{{ driver.time }}">{{ driver.driver_name }}</label>
    <input required type="radio" name="driver" value="{{ driver.time }}" id="{{ driver.time }}">
{% endfor %}
<input required name="card" type="text" minlength="6" maxlength="6">
<button>START</button>
```

My view.

```
def update_driver(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        update_form = UpdateForm(request.POST)
        if update_form.is_valid():
            card = update_form.cleaned_data['card']
            time = update_form.cleaned_data['driver']
            driver = Driver.objects.filter(time=time).first
            driver.card = card
            driver.save()
    return redirect(index)
```

And forms.py

```
class UpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
        fields = ["card", "score", "time", "is_new"]
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: How do you submit the form? Is that START button supposed to do it? It should be `<input type="submit">` unless you have some JavaScript to handle it.

Comment: I thought button it’s just input submit and it worked for me all of the times, when I used it like that.

Comment: It seems you missed a `()` after `Driver.objects.filter(time=time).first`. Code should read `Driver.objects.filter(time=time).first()`

Comment: It still doesn't work